# How to deal with the status of the third confignode in Apache IoTDB cluster to running?

Tags: startup, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now using version 1.3.0 of Apache IoTDB and already build up cluster using IoTDB. Why does the third ConfigNode in my cluster need a while of time to change from `unknown` status to `running` status? (The other two ConfigNodes took shorter time to be running.) When I change a server to serve as the third ConfigNode, it remains `unknown` status all the time. What other ways can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the physical clocks between different confignodes in Apache IoTDB are not aligned. You can check the server time of your cluster, and set them to be the same (even if they only differ 1 minute, it still needs to be changed to the same).